# Puppeteer select option from drowpdown menu using xpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, browser-automation

I'm trying to select one of the optiones from this menu:

[image]

Let's say I want to click on the "Online Webinar" option.

1. I have to click on the input to open up the dropdown menu
2. I have to target the option that I'm looking for using `waitForXPath`, that means that I'm targeting elements for it's text content, not by class or id

This is my HTML structure:

[image]

And this is how I'm targeting the "Online Webinar" in my code:

[image]

And this is the what I'm getting from this code

[image]

As you can see, is not selecting the "Online Webinar" option, and I think that it's because there's a whitespace at the beginning and end of the string that I'm looking to target and I think this is the problem

[image]

However I don't know to workaround this issue, should I look for a way to use the `trim()` method, or there's a Puppeteer way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple solution

```
let venueOption = await page.waitForXPath(`//li[contains(text(),'Online Webinar')]`);
```